# AngularJS app in XUL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox-addon, xul

I am trying to load an entire angular.js app in a XUL window in my Firefox addon

Unfortunately, my angular app does not get loaded if I use (just white page with source code):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<window
    id="test"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    >
  <?xml-stylesheet rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://myapp/content/app/app.css"?>

  <div  xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng:app="myAngular">
    <div data-ng-class="ui-view">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="chrome://myapp/content/app/angular.min.js" />
  <script src="chrome://myapp/content/app/app.js" />
</window>
```

If I use

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<window id="test"
        xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<browser src="chrome://myapp/content/index.html" flex="1" width="100%" height="100%"/>

</window>
```

the app works, but I do not have access to localstorage in my angular.js app.

Is there any way to load the entire angular.js app?

If I "have" to use the browser solution, how can I save and read variables from angular?

Comment: Does it have to xul? Can you make it an xhtml page? Like I just made an angular app in firefox addon 2 days ago: https://github.com/Noitidart/ZooniverseXpert install that addon with https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-extension-installer/ and then go to `about:zoo` and it loads the fully localized (the localization works just like xul, as its an xhtml file). the only diff in xhtml from html is that you have to close all tags either with `<blah />` or wth `<blah></blah>`. Doing an `about:` page is good idea as it gets listed in `about:about` as an app and future launcher pages

Comment: Also in xhtml you have to not use mini attributes, so `<html ngCsp>` would have to be `<html ngCsp="">`

Comment: If I use your plugin as a template and simply plugin my index.html instead of your xhtml it "loads" the html and in the console I can access angular and see that there is a module named "myAngular", but it never gets instantiated. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: You have to update app.js in the resources/scripts folder

Comment: If you need more help with it jump onto irc irc://moznet/extdev or if you dont have an irc client you can use the html5 mibbit client https://client01.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Fmoznet%2Fextdev i can walk you through it in like 10min especially if you have teamviewer

Comment: Oh and you have to do xhtml, otherwise you cannot localize it. Localization is super easy, check it out its already done. Just add a string in the locale file and then call it in.

Comment: I asked in #evtdev and #addons, but did not see you there :) I changed every file and like I said - the files themselves get loaded, I can access angular and such in the console. But it does not render the angular site :(

Comment: Ah I was sleeping! Jump on my name is noida :)